# Statsmodels Installation Error

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, statsmodels

Whenever I tried to install "Statsmodels" using pip or easy_install the following error is showing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qGZk.png)

I have tried to install scipy individually, same thing happens. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing statsmodels is quite easy, when numpy and scipy is available.

Installing scipy (using pip or easy_install = from sources by default) on the other hand is a nightmare on Windows, as it needs a C-Compiler, Fortran-Compiler and for example [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) which is the error shown in your case.

The official docs of scipy [do not recommend this manual install on Windows](https://www.scipy.org/install.html).

A few years ago there were *official prebuilt binaries*, but that's not the case anymore.

A few sources of prebuilt binares are given in the docs above and **i highly recommend [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)**.